# Using Ruby to create folder in google drive

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-drive-api

I am using Ruby and Google Drive API.
How to create a folder in the root location?

Answer (score 0):

A folder in Google Drive is essentially a file with MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`, so you can use the Ruby code in the Reference guide and set the `mimeType` field to that value.

Check the docs for the complete snippet:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert